# laravel search query where by number using hash character

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code below which searches for tags that the first letter is queried against, so the query is like this myurl.com/tags?alpha=E but I want to query things that start with a number how could I query the database when the alpha could use the hash code # representing that it's a number to be queried and return tags that start with a number, checkout my code below

```
public function index()
{
    //
    $tags = null;

    if(Input::get('alpha') != null)
    {
        // alpha could be A,B,C,D,E etc
        $tags = Tag::where('name', 'Like', Input::get('alpha') . '%')->orderBy('name', 'asc')->paginate(40);
    }
    else
    {
        $tags = Tag::orderBy('name', 'asc')->paginate(40);  
    }

    return View::make('tags.index')->with(compact('tags'));
}
```

Comment: I dont understand why you have a separation between numbers and alphabets ?? as far as I know, as long as your tag is a string, it doesn't matter if it starts with a number or an alphabet character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
public function index() {
        $tags = null;
        $alpha = Input::get('alpha');
        if ( preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]$/", $alpha) ) {
            $tags = Tag::where('name', 'Like', Input::get('alpha') . '%')->orderBy('name', 'asc')->paginate(40);
        } else if ( $alpha == "#" ) {
            $tags = Tag::whereRaw("name regexp '^[0-9]'")->orderBy('name', 'asc')->paginate(40);
        } else {
            $tags = Tag::orderBy('name', 'asc')->paginate(40);
        }

        return View::make('tags.index')->with(compact('tags'));
    }
```

**Note that:** to send # character you must use '%23' for alpha value instead of '#' (myurl.com/tags?alpha=%23)